# Как сохранить созданные элементы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть такой код:

```
$(function createTest () {
   standartCount = 2;
   $('#standartAns').click(function () {
      $('#create .jumbotron form').append('<div class="AnsAdd' + standartCount + '"></div><hr>');
      $('#create .jumbotron .AnsAdd' + standartCount).append('<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-md-5"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Добавьте название к вопросу"></div></div>');
      $('#create .jumbotron .AnsAdd' + standartCount).append('<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-md-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="1 вариант ответа"></div></div>');
      $('#create .jumbotron .AnsAdd' + standartCount).append('<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-md-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="2 вариант ответа"></div></div>');
      $('#create .jumbotron .AnsAdd' + standartCount).append('<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-md-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="3 вариант ответа"></div></div>');
      $('#create .jumbotron .AnsAdd' + standartCount).append('<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-md-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="4 вариант ответа"></div></div>');
      standartCount++;
   });
})
```

После обновления страницы, эти элементы пропадают. Как сделать чтобы после обновления они не пропадали?

Comment: а сервер у вас на чем написан? он вам пондобится. Ну как вариант записывать массив в `localStorage` или `sessionStorage` или `coockie`... и при загрузки страницы считывать

Comment: Проблема в том что я плохо разбираюсь в localStorage и sessionStorage, не могли бы вы написать небольшой пример?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let data = [];
  data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item"));
  if (data !== null && data !== undefined){
    data.forEach(function(el){
      $("#data-res").append('<p>'+ el +'</p>');
    });
  }
  
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#data-res").append('<p>'+ $("input").val() +'</p>');
 let data1 = [];
    let d = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item"));
 console.log(d);
 if (d === null || d === undefined){
  data1.push($("input").val());
 }
 else {
  d.forEach(function(elem){
   data1.push(elem);
  });
  data1.push($("input").val());
 }
    //data.push($("input").val());
    localStorage.setItem("item",JSON.stringify(data1));
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" />
<button id="btn">Добавить</button>
<div id="data-res"></div>
</body>
```